# How do I color points using 2 conditions?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter

I would like to color my points in a scattergraph by `Depo` depending on if they meet my `Cutoff` criteria. I tried coloring by `Depo` and using shape for `Cutoff` but this doesn't give me the visual I'm after. I really want the points colored by `Depo` only if the `Cutoff = Good/Maybe` and all the points where the `Cutoff = Bad` black.

```
Depth    Pj         T         Depo    Cutoff
100.69    1.095802    0.9986513    Dri    Good
97.04    1.009357    0.9624445    Pro    Good
74.74    1.039274    0.9880176    Tur    Maybe
106.46    1.054291    0.9873374    Pro    Maybe
109.37    1.117034    0.9913281    Dri    Bad
90.29    1.01166        0.9107071    Pro    Bad
```

I tried this but it doesn't make the bad samples stand out

```
ggplot(MyData, aes(x=Pj, y=T, colour = Depo, shape = Cutoff)) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
df %>%
    mutate(col = factor(ifelse(
        Cutoff %in% c("Good", "Maybe"),
        as.character(Depo),
        NA))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Pj, y = T, colour = col, shape = Cutoff)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text = "Depth    Pj         T         Depo    Cutoff
100.69    1.095802    0.9986513    Dri    Good
97.04    1.009357    0.9624445    Pro    Good
74.74    1.039274    0.9880176    Tur    Maybe
106.46    1.054291    0.9873374    Pro    Maybe
109.37    1.117034    0.9913281    Dri    Bad
90.29    1.01166        0.9107071    Pro    Bad", header = T)
```

Comment: This works exactly how I want it but how do I change NA in the legend to something more meaningful, such as Below Cutoff? @Maurits